# LTE to Wi-fi Handover

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a Linux based device which have LTE and Wi-Fi modules.I can have internet connectivity using LTE which creates ppp interface or wifi which creates wlan.
Need Your Inputs on Handover mechanism from LTE to Wi-fi or vice-versa, if that network is not working as expected.

E.g:- When you are at home and Wifi network is available switch from Mobile data to WiFi.

Regards
S.S.

Comment: Does this not sorta happen automatically?  I would think that the WiFi route would have a lower cost in the routing?

Comment: It would be great if you can share some reference material where i can start on this. I am very new on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No standard defines a handover between Wi-Fi and LTE. Actually we can't even speak about a handover between the two technologies:

- In LTE the UE (e.g. phone) is allocated ressource blocks (frequency and/or time) and when the UE has data to send, it already knows on which frequency or time frame it should send it.
- While with Wi-Fi, you always have to compete along side other terminals to get access to the medium in order to send your data
- And unless your device has multiple antennas and is capable of processing LTE and Wi-Fi streams in the same time, a handover between the two technologies is not feasable

A handover between two inherently distinct network access techonologies is not the right way to go.

I suggest you do it programaticaly; When the LTE signal quality drops you switch the LTE module off and the Wi-Fi module on .. and vice-versa.

Following this method, the IP address of the device might change. Unless this is an inconvinience try my suggestion and keep us posted about the results